# Subscribe to a query

Tags: sql, database

Is there a way in native SQL, SQL database specific (i.e. PostGresQL) or another (NoSQL database) to subscribe to query and receive updates when a entry matches the criteria? For example I have the query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE birthday = today()` is it possible to receive update when a entry matches the criteria instead of using the so called 'pulling' mechanism? The query can be slightly more complex because this idea is required for a solution which send recurring messages based on the user preferences.

Comment: You would need to set up a job to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is not possible to do this in a push/pull way?

Comment: Maybe you can do something similar for simple condition by adding triggers for `insert`, `update`, and `delete`. These triggers can check the conditions and produce some event.

Comment: You can use a job scheduler or a message queuing system, but those are usually separate from the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only database I know that has built-in notifications like this is RebirthDB with a feature called "changefeeds":

> They allow clients to receive changes on a table, a single document,
>   or even the results from a specific query as they happen. Nearly any
>   ReQL query can be turned into a changefeed.

The only problem is that the database began life as RethinkDB, but the company making it folded in 2016, leaving it to the open-source community. It's still alive as "RebirthDB" on GitHub with active development, but the documentation is just a copy of the old Rethink docs with GitHub notices. They have a website url, but no website. I hope they can keep it alive: it's a great idea.

https://github.com/RebirthDB/docs